# Creating a dashboard for Infrastructure consumtion by customer using dynatrace

Tags: dynatrace

I am new to dynatrace.
We have a multi-tenant cloud application. I am working on a POC to check if dynatrace can be used
to create a matrics which will give information about infrastructure usage details by each customer.
These information i will store it either in a table or a file.
For example for Customer1 an entry will be there in a file/db table like ,
RDBMS:200MB, FILES_STORAGE:1GB, JMS:100 etc.

The above information are usage done for a day

Now using dynatrace I want to create a dashboard, the above information should be shown in a timeseries.

Could some one please help me what are features I have to use and learn to achive this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can periodically send the metrics to Dynatrace as "custom metric", see the [documentation](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v1/custom-metrics/).

Note: You cannot send historical values this way, you will send the "current" value periodically to continuously fill the timeseries.

Naturally you can send this much more often than daily, up to seconds-resolution if necessary and then you will get the chart in full resolution.

Then you can use [custom charting](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/dashboards-and-charts/custom-charts-and-tiles/custom-charts/) to chart the metric and "pin" it onto a Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)....I will start reading the links provided by you. I have posted another quetion seeking help for dynatrace  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739726/parsing-log-file-in-dynatrace-and-send-notification  Could you please help me one more time?